# How can I get a Pandas Dataframe out of the Codeforces API?

Tags: python, dataframe, api, analytics

I would like to use the CODEFORCERS API for some Analytics (in Python / SQL / even XLS...).
I tried to get a sufficient Pandas Dataframe but I get a Dataframe with 0 Rows and 13644 columns.
I have no clue how to get a usable Dataframe out of the API.

What I want to do with the data:
Analyse different aspects like scores / participants / score changes / rounds ...

Just pulling the data into an XLS sheet / SQL should work as well.

Best, Kiki

I tried

import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets

contest_list = pd.read_csv("https://codeforces.com/api/contest.list?gym=false")
pd.DataFrame(contest_list)

but got a Dataframe with 0 rows × 13644 columns.

Answer (score 0):

My earlier answer was wrong. I made an assumption that the data on your URL was in CSV format (and that Pandas wouldn't support reading from an HTTP endpoint on `read_csv`... which it does!).

The data on that URL is **not** in CSV format.

It is in JSON format.

Therefore:

```py
contest_list = pd.read_json("https://codeforces.com/api/contest.list?gym=false")
pd.DataFrame(contest_list)
```

However this results in: `[0 rows x 13652 columns]`

This is because the JSON is a complex object that needs a little bit of pre-parsing to make for a nice dataframe

```py
import requests

url = "https://codeforces.com/api/contest.list?gym=false"
response = requests.get(url)

contents = response.json()
results = contents.get("result")
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(df)
```

This results in: `[1667 rows x 8 columns]`

Comment: Ah nice! Thanks you and how can I turn it into a Dataframe then?

Comment: Because if I use df = pd.DataFrame([response]) I still get a Dataframe of 1 rows × 2480 columns